# Help with relays and spot switches

Tags: wiring, switching, bidirectional

[image]I’m working on a shuttle bus and need help wiring the doors to open and close with the limit switches acting as stops (all the way open, and all the way closed). Stupid me cut out the old wiring, thinking I could figure it out. I can get the doors to open and close, but when I put the limit switches in, it cuts all the power in both directions. I have two limit switches which are double pole double throw and the following components, but can’t figure out how to wire everything to make it work properly. Can someone please help me?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Please could you put an image with enough resolution we can read the labelling on the devices on the right?

Comment: I have added clearer image hoping this helps

Answer (score 1):

Put the normally-closed limit switches in series with the forward and reverse switches.  Now SW1 will make it go forwards, unless it's pushing against LIM1.  Same for reverse: SW2 asks for reverse, but can't connect if it's pushed against LIM2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMGnDu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you!! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MichaelKisner Glad it helped.  Just a note as I see you're new: the convention at SE is you upvote ▴ helpful answers, and accept ✅ those if you feel they are the answer to your question.  Have a look at [When someone answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [why voiting is important](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).  And indeed, downvote ▾ those you think are bad!